# how to replace values in dataframe column depending on other column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on NFL data from kaggle competition: https://www.kaggle.com/c/nfl-playing-surface-analytics/data.

**PlayList dataset** has `Temperature` column and some values for temperature are -999. I would like to replace those `-999` with mean value of temperature for each type of stadium.

I have categorized stadium types to six types:

- outdoor
- indoor_closed
- indoor_open
  ...

I tried `groupby`, and also creating new dataframes and merging, but I have a feeling there is simpler solution.
Please find below sample of dataset after below command:
`play_list_df[play_list_df['Temperature']==-999]`

[Initial dataset sorted by temperature values = -999](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR2PS.png)

I would like to replace those -999's with mean values of Temperature specifiic for each category of Stadium.
Below are the mean values that I get using groupby and agg 'mean' function.
`play_list_df[play_list_df['Temperature']!=-999].groupby('StadiumType_cat').mean()`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIrDh.png)
 Thank you in advance for support.

Comment: Please provide a sample dataset and the expected output for that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace all the -999 values with NaN, then groupby the category and use `.transform` with lambda function to fillna with the mean.

It's tough to test since you don't provide a sample dataset (in the future, don't post pictures of the code or data set. Post the actual code, or dataset to be used)

```
import numpy as np
play_list_df['Temperature'] = play_list_df['Temperature'].replace(-999, np.NaN)
play_list_df["Temperature"] = play_list_df.groupby("StadiumType_cat")['Temperature'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works, I will also listen to your hints about the correct posting. I'm new in ML and stackoverflow so your guidance is truely needed. Once again thanks for the support:)